# Adding multiple attendees to recurring event

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, recurring-events

I have created a recurring event (meeting). The same attendees are required for each recurrence. How do I quickly add multiple attendees to all of the recurrences? Right now I have to add each person manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to the "All Events" view, it shows recurring events as 1 item. You can modify the view to include the attendees column and modify using quick edit. I think it'll take all the attendees you enter there for all the events. Haven't tested it though.